# Setting JSpinner for countdown timer

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I want to use a JSpinner to select a time for a countdown timer where the user selects the HR,MIN,SEC where any of these values can be `00`. I was using the `SpinnerDateModel` but the HR cannot be set to `00`

Comment: Have you considered using three separate spinners

Comment: I probably will if I can't come up with a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The default format of date display by the JSpinner is locale-dependent, but you can customize the date formatting by explicitly setting a [JSpinner.DateEditor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.DateEditor.html) instance with your desired format as [the spinner's editor component](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html#setEditor-javax.swing.JComponent-):

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel());
spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "HH:mm:ss"));
```

The `HH` there will ensure the hour is displayed with leading zeros.